# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::validate()

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want that when the validator fails go to same part of the register form in the home.blade.php and not to the begining of the page.

Can someone help me to do that?
Registercontroller.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator =  Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/#register')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
}


/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $customization = New Customization();
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],  
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'cuenta' => $data['cuenta'],
        'avatar' => "https://i0.wp.com/www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/user.png?fit=256%2C256&quality=100&ssl=1",
    ]);
        $customization->user_id = $user->id;
        $customization->save();
    return $user;
}
```

This is the error on laravel:

Pls i need some help

[Error Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS6QN.png)

Comment: Have you made some changes to the default files shipped with Laravel? Which version are you using? I can't seem to reproduce the error with what you've provided.

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.23

Comment: @JuanSpada can you share your function where you are redirecting ?

Comment: sorry i cudnt post all the controller, i just edit the original post with the funciton

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the following from your `validator` function:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/#register')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

The validator function is expecting an instance of `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` to be returned.

So change to:

```
return Validator::make([
    // Your rules here
]);
```

The controller will automatically redirect back with the errors on failure.

If you want to redirect somewhere else on failure, what you could do is overwrite the `register` method by adding the following in your controller:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/#register')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: I should change the create function with the redirect function ? Or where i put the function you make

Comment: @JuanSpada You should add the `register` method in your controller and update the `validator` method like I've mentioned.

Comment: but where i have to add the data like phone email etc, sorry im so new in this.

Comment: @JuanSpada No problem. Just leave it in your validator method. I'm only asking you to remove the if condition from the method and to return the validator.

Comment: @JuanSpada No problem. Please mark my answer as the correct one when you have a minute :)

Comment: I do it but dosnt appear becouse im new